# Is any way to hosting ASP.NET MVC and .NET 6 API at the same application in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-6.0

I'm migrating partially from ASP.NET MVC to .NET 6 API.
On IIS I have application to hosting ASP.NET MVC, f.ex https://localhost/Company/app.

On https://localhost/Company/app/apiv2 I would to host .NET 6 Api.

Is possible to create this configuration?

I try do it, but .NET 6 Api not responding. If I host .NET 6 Api as separated application, working good (https://localhost/apiv2).

[image]

Comment: That's not called "at the same application". As shown in IIS Manager, they are still different applications, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis You have to configure routing rules in ASP.NET MVC web app to ignore the .NET 6 web app URLs. Otherwise, traffic cannot go through.

Comment: Yes, as Lex Li said you need to set MVC to ignore alias of .net6 app. Otherwise mvc may think it points to controller or action. Another thing is hosting these applications in different app pools. Different applications should in different app pools when they in a same site.